# React Native importing function from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

I am wondering if I import a function from another file, am I also importing all the files that is imported in the file of the function? For example:

auth.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, View, Text, ScrollView, ... } from 'react-native';
import ModuleA from './modules/ModuleA';
import ModuleB from './modules/ModuleB';
import Module99 from './modules/Module99;

export const function1 = () => {
    {/* some function using ModuleA */}
}

export const function2 = (param) => {
    if(something)
        {/* some function using Module99 */}
    else
        {/* some function using ModuleB */}
}
```

Screen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { function2 } from '../auth';

export default class Screen extends React.Component {
    {/* use function2 in some function or render */
}
```

My question is, when I import function2 from auth.js, am I importing all the modules and other files that is imported in auth.js? Or am I just importing the module that will be used by function2.

Also, function2 will use different module depending on the param, by calling function2 from my Screen, will my Screen also import all modules, or just Module99 and moduleB, or just the specific module inside the if else statement?

I have read a lot of the documentations on how importing works in react native but still couldn't really understand the flow.
Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By doing this `import function2 from '../auth';` you are importing nothing as its not **default** export. Also no modules will automatically be imported in `screen.js`.
You will have to import explicitly the modules(ModuleA, ModuleB ets) if you also need to use in `screen.js`

If you want to use `function2` in `screen.js` the you need to import it like this

```
import { function2 } from '../auth';
```

You can also use `import * as fromAuth from '../auth';` to import all

Usage: `fromAuth.function2()`

Import **without** curly braces `{}` is used for importing defaults.(which has been exported using default `keyword`)

There are 4 types of exports:

- Named exports (several per module)
- Default exports (one per module)
- Mixed named & default exports
- Cyclical Dependencies

Here are some Import examples from MDN

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
```

Find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, yes I missed the curly bracket, still, my question is when function2 is using another module, does all the module in auth.js also being imported when I am calling function2 from Screen?

Comment: No, the modules imported in `auth.js` can only be used in `auth.js`. If you also want to use them in `screen.js` then import there as well.

Comment: I mean, will it consume memory, as in my auth.js, I may import a lot of modules, and if it consume memory, I am going to separate some functions.

Comment: No there will be no memory issue you can import as many modules as you want in a single module. Webpack will simply know that this module is dependent on several modules and will bundle them together.

Comment: You can see `auth.js` module is just exporting two functions `function1` and `function2` . So only these functions can be imported from `auth.js` not the other modules that are imported in `auth.js`.